# When manually refreshing the vue page, how to ensure that the parameters passed in before still exist?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I passed some parameters from A.vue page to B.vue page, and I received these parameters in **created()** in B.vue page.

However, when i refresh B.vue page manually,these parameters in created() are undefined,please tell me which is the best way to keep these parameters still exist, thanks!

Here is the way to pass parameters to B.vue in A.vue page:

```
 toSelect(evt, row) {
      this.$router.push({ name: '/oms/order/po/detail/', params: { poId: row.poId, pageList: this.pagination } })
    },
```

In B.vue page to receive:

```
created() {
    this.routeParams = this.$route.params
    let storage = this.routeParams
    console.log(storage)
 }
```

Comment: Hitting browser refresh when running a Vue application reinitializes the application, so that is probably why your parameters are undefined.  Not sure since I don't see all your application code.  Why are you wanting to refresh the browser?

Comment: @Tim,In fact, we should consider all possible situations when users use our project. Thanks for your explanation, although I think this is not the best way, but in the end I found that we can achieve it through `sessionStorage`.